# Delphi adding to registry failed

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer-11, delphi-7, browser-addons

I am trying to add values to Internet Explorer's Registry key from an addon.  My understanding is if `OpenKey()` doesn't find the Registry key, then it creates the key because of the `true` parameter I am using.  But it's not being created, and the function returns false.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
procedure DoInitialization;
var
  ...
  reg1: TRegistry;
begin
  reg1 := tRegistry.Create(KEY_ALL_ACCESS);
  try 
    if reg1.OpenKey('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy\{B93642D4-0A6D-11DF-AD36-FF4756D89593}', true) then begin    
      reg1.WriteString('AppPath', ClientDir);
      reg1.WriteInteger('Policy', $00000003);
      reg1.WriteString('AppName', 'xxxxxxxx.exe');
    end else
      ShowMessage('False');
  finally
    reg1.CloseKey;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.OpenKey Read the documentation, it seems clear to me

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake in the example.  I originally tried it with True and it wasn't writing to the registry.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to be something other than a regurgitation of tags. *Delphi Internet Explorer Delphi* is all useless noise, especially since your question actually has nothing to do with IE or a browser add-on. Your title should convey some meaning about your question that will be of use to a future reader seeing it in a list of search results to differentiate it from others. Your question is about TRegistry. Also see the documentation, especially `TRegistry.RootKey`.

Comment: Read Registry.LastError after the failure to see why it failed. Also, you leak Registry.

Answer (score 1):

The root key is to be set in the `RootKey` property, not the key.

```
reg1.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
if reg1.OpenKey('Software\...', True) then begin
  ....
```

In fact, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is the default so strictly speaking you don't need to set it. But it is, in my opinion, helpful to be explicit.

If that fails then likely you have got a mistake in the registry key string, or perhaps the user does not have sufficient rights. Use the `LastError` property of `reg1` to find out why the call failed.

Note that you leak `reg1`. You need to destroy the object in the `finally` block.

Comment: the "..." means there was more code.  I freed reg1 but it was cut off from the example.

Comment: The call to Free needs to be in the finally block in the question and it's pointless calling CloseKey, destroying the object is enough.

Comment: Again there is more code.  I added the "..." because this is where it's failing, not later.

Comment: I tried reg1.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER; and I'm still getting false returned.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to argue with me.  Please I'm trying to figure out why reg1.openkey is not working.  I am not asking for help on what to do after this.

Comment: FOCUS PLEASE!  I am asking for help with openKey not the leaks.

For the error code I tried reg1.LastError and the compiler didn't like that.Tried SysErrorMessage(GetLastError) and got "operation completed successfully"

Comment: I know. Which is why I added the comment about your leaks as an afterthought. I was just correcting you when you kicked back. I guess you have an old version of Delphi without LastError. You didn't say which version you use. Older versions don't let you obtain error codes at all. GetLastError won't help because the error code doesn't travel that way. It's the return value from the call to RegCreateKeyEx. Checking that under the debugger would help.

Comment: I am using Delphi 7.  I'm modifying old code that the company plans to upgrade before the end of the year.

Comment: Enable Debug DCUs, step into the OpenKey call, and check the return value of the call to RegCreateKeyEx. That's the error code. Learning how to debug these sort of problems will be really useful for you.

Comment: @Brian: `TRegistry` does not have a `LastError` property in Delphi 7, and the Registry API does not use `GetLastError()` to report errors. The only way you will be able to get the error code is to either 1) step into `OpenKey()` with the debugger, or 2) call the Win32 API `RegCreateKeyEx()` function directly.

Answer (score 1):

DON'T use `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`, that requires admin rights to use. In this situation, you are just writing values to the key, so all you need to use is `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead. Don't request more rights than you actually need.

Also, you need to use the `RootKey` property to specify `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, do not include it in the key path string.

And, you are leaking the `TRegistry` object.

Try this instead:

```
procedure DoInitialization;
var
  ...
  reg1: TRegistry;
begin
  reg1 := TRegistry.Create(KEY_SET_VALUE);
  try 
    reg1.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if reg1.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy\{B93642D4-0A6D-11DF-AD36-FF4756D89593}', true) then
    begin    
      try
        reg1.WriteString('AppPath', ClientDir);
        reg1.WriteInteger('Policy', $00000003);
        reg1.WriteString('AppName', 'xxxxxxxx.exe');
      finally
        reg1.CloseKey;
      end;
    end else
      ShowMessage('False');
  finally
    reg1.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Why would you need admin right in HKCU? I agree that KEY_ALL_ACCESS is over the top but I didn't mention it because I didn't think it mattered in HKCU.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` includes rights to alter security access and ownership, so requires an admin to use it

Comment: Don't you also need KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY in case the key needs to be created.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not in this case, no, since the `hKey` passed to `RegCreateKeyEx()` is the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key itself. `KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY` would be needed if you opened the `ElevationPolicy` key first, then created the `{B93642D4-0A6D-11DF-AD36-FF4756D89593}` key relative to it

Comment: In my tests `HKCU` and `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` (the [default values](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.Create) for Delphi `TRegistry`) work fine for reading/writing/creating/deleting keys and values with non-admin and not-elevated admin users.

Comment: @JRL it is still not a good idea to request more rights than you actually need for any given operation

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It did not work again, but when I change the window user to one with more permissions it did work, so my main problem appears to be a rights issue.